# Inject Maven Plugin Dependencies runtime

Tags: java, maven, runtime, maven-plugin, gradle-plugin

is it possible to inject dependencies in maven plugin and/or gradle plugin at runtime. I know you can add dependencies in plugin in pom.xml but i want those dependencies to be runtime as i want to be able to inject them something like this
`mvn <plugin>:<goal> <arg=pass dependencies here)`

This plugin is not in repo pom.xml so i want to run mvn cli to execute this plugin outside of the project. Has anyone done this

[Add Plugin Dependencies Runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuzXn.png)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: its a custom plugin, i used a bad example of `spring boot plugin` in the screenshot. I dont know if that is feasible out of box, if it requires plugin code change, i am ok with that. I can customize the plugin code. I just have to be able to pass different dependencies and/or upgraded dependency version to plugin, since i have to run this in 100s of repo i cant update every project's pom. If it requires plugin code change, if you know if any open source plugin that does this, i would appreciate it if you can point me to that plugin

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem.  The Maven way IS to fix it in your hundreds of repositories, and to do it properly, and doing it in other ways will cause you more problems down the road.   You may want to look into XSLT to manipulate the pom's

Answer (score 0):

use  tag for doing this. sample below here :

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
        <version>version</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: This wont work as i have to add this dependency in the pom and i cant do that for 1000s of project and also dependencies can change or upgraded so i need this for easily pluggable for future upgrade and enhancements.

Comment: Thousands of projects?  What on earth is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You could define an additional property like:

```
<properties>
    <plugin.dependency.version>someDefaultVersion</plugin.dependency.version>
</properties>
```

and use it in the plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.verision}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>groupid</groupId>
                    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
                    <version>${plugin.dependency.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

By doing so you should be able to define plugin's dependency via command line using this command:

```
mvn org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:yourGoal -Dplugin.dependency.version=runtimeDepenencyVersion
```

Comment: this wont for me, Spring Boot plugin was a bad example i guess, its a different plugin. And that plugin is not added to all the project. I have 1000s of repo where i want to run this plugin goal but with different runtime dependencies. In order for your solution to work, i have to add this plugin to every project.

Comment: Also i just realized, i cant add plugin in settings.xml

Comment: Are those repositories sharing the same pom parent? If so, then the plugin could only be added to the parent pom so all projects would benefit from it.  
Since you said that you can customize the plugin code I assume that you can also release it. The other option would be to release a bunch of different versions of the same plugin, each one having different dependencies. Then you could run your plugin as: `mvn yourPluginGroupId:yourPluginName:specificVersionOfThePluginWhichHasNeededDependencies:yourGoal`